# Infix to Postfix conversion c++

Tags: c++, class, stack, infix-notation

I am trying to convert from infix to postfix, and then evaluating the postfix expression to get the final answer. I am having a severe problem though, because for some reason the conversion is not working at all. For example, when I input the first infix expression: 24 + 33 * ( 7 - 5 ) + 8 / 3 it outputs 24 33 7 5 45404243 8 34743 which is obviously very wrong. I am not really sure where the problem is though. Below I have included all of the code needed. I also had to create my own stack class, so I will include it too if it would help. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include "stacks.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

bool IsOperand(char C)
{
    if(C >= '0' && C <= '9') return true;
    return false;
}

bool IsOperator(char C)
{
    if(C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/')
        return true;

    return false;
}
int GetOperatorWeight(char op)
{
    int weight = -1;
    switch(op)
    {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            weight = 1;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            weight = 2;
    }
    return weight;
}

int HasHigherPrecedence(char op1, char op2)
{
    int op1Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op1);
    int op2Weight = GetOperatorWeight(op2);

    return op1Weight > op2Weight ?  true: false;
}

int PerformOperation(char operation, int operand1, int operand2)
{
    if(operation == '+') return operand1 +operand2;
    else if(operation == '-') return operand1 - operand2;
    else if(operation == '*') return operand1 * operand2;
    else if(operation == '/') return operand1 / operand2;

    else cout<<"Unexpected Error \n";
    return -1; 
}

bool IsNumericDigit(char C)
{
    if(C >= '0' && C <= '9') return true;
    return false;
}

int evalPost(string item)
{
    stacks S;

    for(int i = 0;i< item.length();i++) {


        if(item[i] == ' ' || item[i] == ',') continue;

        else if(IsOperator(item[i])) {

            int operand2 = stoi(S.stackTop()); S.pop();
            int operand1 = stoi(S.stackTop()); S.pop();

            int result = PerformOperation(item[i], operand1, operand2);

            S.push(to_string(result));
        }
        else if(IsNumericDigit(item[i]))
        {
            int operand = 0;
            while(i<item.length() && IsNumericDigit(item[i]))
            {
                operand = (operand*10) + (item[i] - '0');
                i++;
            }

            i--;

            S.push(to_string(operand));
        }
    }
    return stoi(S.stackTop());
}



string infToPost(string item)
{
    stacks S;
    string postfix = "";
    for(int i = 0;i< item.length();i++) {
        cout<<postfix<<endl;
        if(item[i] == ' ')
            postfix +=item[i];

        else if(IsOperator(item[i]))
        {

            while(!S.empty() && S.stackTop() != "(" && HasHigherPrecedence(*(S.stackTop().c_str()),item[i]))
            {
                postfix+= S.stackTop();
                S.pop();
            }
            S.push(to_string(item[i]));
            //S.pop();
        }

        else if(IsOperand(item[i]))
        {
            postfix +=item[i];
        }

        else if (item[i] == '(')
        {
            S.push(to_string(item[i]));
        }

        else if(item[i] == ')')
        {
            while(!S.empty() && S.stackTop() !=  "(") {
                postfix += S.stackTop();
                S.pop();
            }
            S.pop();
        }
    }


    while(!S.empty()) {
        postfix += S.stackTop();
        S.pop();
    }

    return postfix;
}

int main()
{
    string selection="";
    string infix;
    string postfix;
    string eval;
    cout<<"***********************************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Read an expression in infix notation."<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Convert infix to postfix."<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Evaluate the expression using postfix notation."<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"***********************************************************"<<endl;
    cout<<"Select: ";
    getline(cin, selection);
//    cin>>selection;
//    cin.ignore();
    while (selection>"4" || selection<"1")
    {
        cout<< "Please enter a different choice (1-4): ";
        getline(cin, selection);
    }
    while(selection!="4")
    {

        if (selection=="1")
        {
            cout<<"Enter an infix expression: ";
            getline(cin,infix);
            cout<<"\n";
        }

        if(selection=="2")
        {
            cout<<"Infix expression: "<<infix<<endl;
            postfix = infToPost(infix);
            cout<<"Postfix expression: "<<postfix<<endl;
            cout<<"\n";
        }

        if(selection=="3")
        {
            cout<<"Infix expression: "<<infix<<endl;
            eval = evalPost(postfix);
            cout<<"Evaluation of this expression: "<<endl;
            cout<<"\n";
        }

        selection = "";
        cout<<"***********************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Read an expression in infix notation."<<endl;
        cout<<"2. Convert infix to postfix."<<endl;
        cout<<"3. Evaluate the expression using postfix notation."<<endl;
        cout<<"4. Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"***********************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Select: ";
        getline(cin,selection);
        //cin.ignore();
        while (selection>"4" || selection<"1")
        {
            cout<< "Please enter a different choice (1-4): ";
            getline(cin, selection);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Thank you for using my program."<<endl;
    return 0;

}
```

STACK CLASS HEADER

```
#ifndef __Programming_Assingment_3__stacks__
#define __Programming_Assingment_3__stacks__
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//define the stacks class
class stacks
{
public:
    //constructor
    stacks();
    //push function
    void push(string item);
    //pop function
    void pop();
    //function to get top of stack
    string stackTop();
    //check if stack is empty
    bool empty();
private:
    //create vector and integer
    int top;
    vector<string> sstack;
};

#endif /* defined(__Programming_Assingment_3__stacks__) */
```

STACK CLASS CPP FILE

```
#include "stacks.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//Contstructor
stacks::stacks()
{
    top = -1;
}

//push the item onto the stack
void stacks::push(string item)
{
    sstack.push_back(item);
    top++;
}

//check if the stack is empty
bool stacks::empty()
{
    if (top==-1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

//delete the last item on the stack
void stacks::pop()
{
    try{
        if (sstack.size()==0) throw 0;
    } catch(int err){
        cout<<"stack is empty."<<endl;
        cout<<"Cannot pop an item."<<endl;
        return;
    }
    sstack.pop_back();
    top--;
}

//get the top of the stack
string stacks::stackTop()
{
    try{
        if (sstack.size()==0) throw 0;
    } catch (int err) {
        cout<< "stack is empty."<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    return (sstack[top]);
}
```

Comment: I have been debugging like crazy (or at least trying to). And I have not had much luck. It seems to correctly store the numbers in the postfix variable until it is time to add the operator to the end. When that happens, it goes a little crazy and I don't know why. For some reason, I think the stack never gets anything into it and I don't know why.

Comment: Okay, I just uncommented one of the S.pop()'s I had, and it drastically changed my output. I now get 24  33   7  5 40  8  3 when I input what I mentioned earlier. But I still don't know what is happening with the operators and why they aren't working with the stack.

Comment: *"I also had to create my own stack class, so I will include it too..."* - it'd be a much better idea to write your code to use `std::stack`, then once it's working see if it works with your own stack... if not at least you know where to debug.

Comment: I tried to use the normal stack class, but when I did it didn't even output what I already had which is pretty close. I think the way I laid it out lends itself towards my stack class instead of the standard one.

Comment: Just a few notes: Firstly, extract a minimal example. All that user interaction (input/output) and the split into multiple files should not be necessary to demonstrate the problem, to name a few things. Then, what is the exact output of your program? What did you expect? Those should be provided anytime you post questions here! Then, check your code where you detect errors and then go on and ignore them. Your stack class does a horrible job at that.

Comment: I think I have it outputting the correct postfix now. But the evaluation of the postfix is not working. I am getting the error: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion" I am expecting it output 92. This is when the infix I put in is 24 + 33 * ( 7 - 5 ) + 8 / 3

Answer (score 1):

When you push an operator on your stack using this line:

```
S.push(to_string(item[i]));
```

the `to_string` is taking the character and treating it as an integer. This results in strings such as "43" for '+' and "45" for '-'.

Instead of this, you want to construct a string with just that character in it. One way to do this is using the string constructor that takes a count and a char value. Use a count of 1.

```
S.push(std::string(1, item[i]));
```

Edit: Here is the `infoToPost` function with the changes. Do not change any of the other `to_string` calls in the other methods, as they are still required (because you want to convert the integer values to strings).

```
string infToPost(string item)
{
    stacks S;
    string postfix = "";
    for (int i = 0; i< item.length(); i++) {
        cout << postfix << endl;
        if (item[i] == ' ')
            postfix += item[i];

        else if (IsOperator(item[i]))
        {

            while (!S.empty() && S.stackTop() != "(" && HasHigherPrecedence(*(S.stackTop().c_str()), item[i]))
            {
                postfix += S.stackTop();
            S.pop();
            }
            S.push(string(1, item[i]));
            //S.pop();
        }

        else if (IsOperand(item[i]))
        {
            postfix += item[i];
        }

        else if (item[i] == '(')
        {
            S.push(string(1, item[i]));
        }

        else if (item[i] == ')')
        {
            while (!S.empty() && S.stackTop() != "(") {
                postfix += S.stackTop();
                S.pop();
            }
            S.pop();
        }
    }


    while (!S.empty()) {
        postfix += S.stackTop();
        S.pop();
    }

    return postfix;
}
```

Comment: Okay, so that helped a lot! It removed the 40's that were showing up. But the operators are still nonexistent in the output and I am really confused by it. So now, my out put is  24  33   7  5   8  3

Comment: Hmm, worked OK for me (note that I used the std::stack, so that might still be your problem). Did you also change the '(' handler?

Comment: I did change the '(' handler. Let me quickly try it with the normal stack class. If it works, then obviously the problem is in my class

Comment: Okay, so when I used the normal class I got this: 24  33   7  5 -  8  3/+*+             Is that correct? From what I have that is wrong. I also get that answer when I use my stack class and remove one of the pop statements( kind of weird)

Comment: It is wrong, but it is close. You should step through in the debugger if you can and pay close attention to the `GetOperatorWeight` function. What you have at the moment is what you would get if all operators have the same precedence.

Comment: I am so close now, I changed my precedence around and now my output is 24  33   7  5 - * 8  3/++         So just one too many plusses. It still isn't evaluating it correctly either though

Comment: And your result is OK, you are just assigning it into a `string`, rather than an `int` result. This gives you the opposite effect you had before, where it is now treating the `int` as a `char`. You also are not printing the result anywhere.

Comment: I return the result to the variable postfix later on in the main function. I print it from there. So how would you recommend I handle the evaluation function? Should I convert everything to int?

Comment: Use:  `int val = evalPost(postfix); cout << "Evaluation of this expression: " << val << endl;` (On two lines)

Comment: Note that you are only doing integer arithmetic, so you expected output is 92 for the sample expression.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice I forgot to print it. But even so, I get this error: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::invalid_argument: stoi: no conversion" When I try to evaluate the postfix. This happens here: int operand2 = stoi(S.stackTop());

Comment: Could be related to your stack implementation - did you ever work out why you had to remove one of the pop statements? You could always post your stack code as an edit to your question (at the bottom, don't remove the current code).

Comment: I am assuming that means that the stoi conversion is unnecessary, but if I remove there is an error saying it cannot convert from string to int automatically.

Comment: Let me add it in real quick

Comment: I added it in, but I never did figure out why it was acting weird.

Comment: I started again with your original code, changed a couple of `to_string` calls (only the operator ones), fixed the `break` in the `GetOperatorWeight` and changed the ouput to the one I posted above and got back the result of 92. If you aren't getting this then you must have changed something else.

Comment: I don't know what I am changing. I took what i originally had and changed all to_string I had into the format you suggested. I also changed the GetOperatorWeight function to work, And I have the correct output now too. But I am still getting the error.

Comment: I would hate to ask but could you possibly show me a snippet of what you changed from my original code? Because I am having problems at int operand2 = stoi(S.stackTop());

Comment: That would be the difference - my change: "changed a couple of to_string calls (only the operator ones)" your change: "changed all to_string I had into the format you suggested". Don't change the operand and result `to_string` calls, as you actually do want to convert those integers to strings.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much for your help tonight! You've been an amazing help!