# Can I use a std::string variable as an argument to an operator?

Tags: c++

For example, if I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    string a = "(b + c)";
    
    cout << (4 * a) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to have string `a` interpreted *literally* as if the code had said `cout << (4 * (b + c)) << "\n";`?

Comment: No that's not possible this way.

Comment: Not without adding some sort of interpreter that can evaluate mathematical  expressions. There's is nothing built-in into C++ for this.

Comment: This would require either "reflection" which does not currently exist in vanilla C++ or using a "symbolic math" library to evaluate such an expression

Comment: I have a feeling OP comes from Python background. No OP. C++ does not let you hold its finger and spoon feed stuff. If you want it done, code it yourself. On a lighter note, what you are doing is multiplying a string with and int which makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: @NathanOliver It seems like the asker's goal is for the output to be `"12"`, not `"(4 * (b + c))"`

Comment: @NathanPierson Yeah, just noticed that when editing.  comment removed

Comment: Understood. And yes, coming from Python. Thanks anyway, folks.

Comment: @Alex, you might want to look into expression evaluation. Hint: It requires knowledge of something called postfix expression. This link might prove helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596911/infix-to-postfix-conversion-c

Comment: In truth, I was attempting to simplify the problem, but may have gone too far. The answer I'm really trying to solve is how to unpack a tuple when I don't know the size in advance.

Comment: @Alex Could you update the Q with that?  A tuples size is a compile time constant, so it should be relatively easy to get.  Can you show an example of what you would like to do with the tuple?

Comment: [even in python](https://www.online-python.com/XNxbJHSae1), you have to do extra to get 12 out

Comment: @Alex Since the question you now mention in the comments is so different from the one you have currently asked and since you've gotten at least one good answer to the current question, I recommend that you ask a new question instead of editing this one (which would make the good answer really confusing).

Comment: Thank you @Tedlyngmo. That's what I've done. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928707/how-to-unpack-tuple-of-unknown-length

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. C++ is not (designed to be) an interpreted language.

Although it's theoretically possible to override operators for different types, it's very non-recommended to override operators that don't involve your own types. Defining an operator overload for `std::string` from the standard library may break in future. It's just a bad idea.

But, let's say you used a custom type. You could write a program that interprets the text string as a arithmetic expression. The core of such program would be a parser. It would be certainly possible, but the standard library doesn't provide such parser for you.

Furthermore, such parser wouldn't be able to make connection between the "b" in the text, and the variable `b`. At the point when the program is running, it has no knowledge of variable names that had been used to compile the program. You would have to specify such information using some form of data structure.

P.S. You forgot to include the header that defines `std::string`.

Answer (score -5):

```
#include<string>
///...
auto a=std::to_string(b+c);
std::cout<<4*std::stoi(a)<<std::endl;
```

You can just use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) and [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).