# How to unpack tuple of unknown length?

Tags: c++

There are three potential directions I can see.

1. `std::tie()`
2. Structured bindings, i.e. `auto (var1, var2, var3...) = t;`
3. `std::get<?>(t)`

I have tuple size from this:

```
int tupleSize = tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value;
```

How can I use `tupleSize` to unpack the tuple?

In case it's not clear, I want to be able to copy and paste a tuple of any size in and be able to compile and run the code without changing anything else.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the values, after you've extracted them?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with those values, you might like [`std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply).

Comment: I'd like to do arithmetic on the numeric values, and concatenation on the strings and char*'s.

Comment: Some context would be really nice. Also, the type of `std::tuple_size` isn't `int`.

Comment: Adding a bunch of elements together can be done using a fold expression like `std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return (args + ...); }, tuple_variable)`.  The technique to use really depends on the operation that needs to be done.

Comment: The tuple contains various types, so I won't be able to add every element.

I have a tuple of strings, ints, doubles, char*s, etc. I need to be able to add numeric values and concatenate string values depending on the type.

Comment: A common way to handle that is to use a helper function.  Inside the function you would check if the variable passed in is a numeric type, if it is, return it's value, if not, return `0`.  Using a helper like that would give you `std::apply([](auto&&... args) { return (to_number(args) + ...); }, tuple_variable)`

Comment: How do I pass args if I don't know its type though? In the helper function, I'll need to specify its type, no?

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: you don't need to know the type.  `to_number` could be implemented like `template <typename T> auto to_number(T&& t) { if constexpr (std::is_arithmetic_v<T>) return t; else return 0; }`

Comment: Please specify your problem more precisely. When you add new information PLEASE [edit] your question instead adding comments, so users have full picture after reading just a question and do not have to scan comments.  Best way to specify a problem it is to provide test which should pass, you can start from this point: https://godbolt.org/z/PWrccT

Answer (score 0):

Comments under question

> I'd like to do arithmetic on the numeric values, and concatenation on the strings and char*'s. –
> `Alex`
>
> ...
>
> The tuple contains various types, so I won't be able to add every element. I have a tuple of strings, ints, doubles, char*s, etc. I need to be able to add numeric values and concatenate string values depending on the type. –
> `Alex`

I understand this this way:

```cpp
template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add_items(const T1& a, const T2& b)
{
    return a + b;
}

auto add_items(const char* a, const char* b)
{
    return std::string{a} + b;
}

template<typename ...Ts, size_t ...indexes>
auto add_tuples_hepler(const std::tuple<Ts...>& a, const std::tuple<Ts...>& b, std::index_sequence<indexes...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(add_items(std::get<indexes>(a), std::get<indexes>(b))...);
}

template<typename ...Ts>
auto add_tuples(const std::tuple<Ts...>& a, const std::tuple<Ts...>& b)
{
    return add_tuples_hepler(a, b, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>{});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/a1bdbKKhh

Still I'm not convinced since lots of details are missing in question and comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this indirectly by filtering for different type categories.

```
  template <template <typename> typename Cond, typename... Ts>  //
  constexpr static auto extractTup(std::tuple<Ts...> const& tup) {
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) == 0) {
      return tup;
    } else {
      auto const head = [](auto const& x0, auto const&...) {
        return std::tuple{x0};
      };
      auto const tail = [](auto const&, auto const&... xs) {
        return std::tuple{xs...};
      };
      using T0 = std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
      if constexpr (Cond<T0>::value) {
        return std::tuple_cat(std::apply(head, tup),
                              extractTup<Cond>(std::apply(tail, tup)));
      } else {
        return extractTup<Cond>(std::apply(tail, tup));
      }
    }
  }
```

## Examples

For example you can extract all values that are integral and then add them up in an extra `std::apply` call:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string, float, unsigned, char const*> test = {
  -1, std::string{"hello"}, 3.14, 42, " world"
};
auto const inttp = extractTup<std::is_integral>(test);
auto const intsum = std::apply([](auto const&... i) { return (i + ...); }, inttp);
// intsum == 41
```

Similarly you can extract all strings and concatenate them:

```
template <typename T> struct is_stringy : std::false_type {};
template <> struct is_stringy<std::string> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_stringy<char const*> : std::true_type {};
template <> struct is_stringy<char*> : std::true_type {};
template <std::size_t N> struct is_stringy<char const[N]> : std::true_type {};
template <std::size_t N> struct is_stringy<char[N]> : std::true_type {};
```

.

```
auto const strtp = extractTup<is_stringy>(test);
// -> {std::string{"hello"}, " world"}
```

## [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4jnG8ccGa)